# Authentication with website, mobile app, and webservice

Tags: web-services, authentication, oauth, openid

I am creating a service that will include a website, a mobile app, and a web service.

Both the website and mobile app will talk to the web service to interact with the database and any other backend items.

I would like users to be able to log in with other services (such as google, facebook, twitter, etc.)

I have two questions in implementing this:

1.) Should I use OpenID or OAuth? I'm not sure which is better for the situation. I have no need to actually access features from a users account, I just want them to be able to log in with accounts they already have,

2.) Where should I implement the authentication? Do I have to implement it both on the website and on the mobile app, or could I have both talk to the web service and do the authentication there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just doing authentication and not syncing any account details, I think OpenID is the way to go. From a security standpoint, I would say to implement your authentication on the website and on the app and not in the webservice. You want to handle credentials the least amount possible and especially avoid sending the credentials via webservice if not using SSL.

Comment: Thanks, will take that approach.